# Parse search results

Tags: parsing

I would like to go to [this site](http://food.guidingstars.com/Templates/FoodFinder.aspx?word=fat), click on every food item listed, click on "View More Details," and copy the entire Nutrition Facts label into a text editor.

I am stuck in a few places:

- First, when I click "View page source" on the list of food items, I do not see < a> < /a> for each listing, and the search result parsers I've seen seem to rely on that html tag.
- Second, I do not know how to write a script to actually follow the link to each food item.
- Third, I do not know how to tell the script to click "View More Details."

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, all of the things that you seem to need help with are a significant amount of work.

I'll give you a hint.  The food lists are loaded via ajax.  Notice the PageNo parameter.  Use regular expressions to find the links in the results.

From Google dev tools:

Url: http://food.guidingstars.com/ajax/pages/foodfindergetfood.aspx

Query Parameters:
_:1336455942029
:
categoryID:-1
sortBy:GuidingStars
PageNo:2
Filter:-1
back:word=fat
pathBreadCrumbs:
word:fat